# Вывести результат, если данные совпадает с другой таблицой

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать выборку из бд, если данные со значением совпадает с другой таблицой, например как вывести значение Москва с таблицы users, если оно совпадает с другой таблицей

```html
       <?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_street', true) ) :
require 'connect.php';
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
    printf ("if (city == '".$row['name']."') {
    $('#mydiv').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');}"
    );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
         endif; ?>
```

Это отвечает за выборку, проблема в том, что она выводит все значение

Comment: Опишите структуру обеих таблиц, и какие поля в них должны совпадать для того, чтобы строки попали в выборку.

Comment: Это таблица users http://prnt.sc/d279pc

Comment: Я рад за таблицу users, но с чем она совпасть то должна. что за вторая таблица. А вообще google "sql join"

Comment: Проблема в том, что данные о городе видны только на самой странице, поэтому и стоит скрипт, в бд о городе объявления не слова